Count just working days (exclude weekends and public holidays) and add filter that a query
I want to add a filter to a query which grabs dates till last 5 WORKING DAYS.
declare @DataRetentionPeriod INT =5
  Delete FROM dbo.table1 pt
   WHERE   CONVERT(varchar,pt.ptStampDateTime, 112) < CONVERT( VARCHAR, DATEADD(DAY, @DataRetentionPeriod * -1, GETDATE()), 112) 

So, I want to delete from table1 but want to retain data in that table till last 5 working days i.e., if the script runs on Monday then it should not count saturday and sunday in the filter and should delete records till last Friday - last weeks data should not be deleted. And if there is any public holiday in the last week then it should add move one more day back to keep 5 working days data.
I have a function which gives me last working day of the @date provided -
 select dbo.fn_previous_working_day(@date)

If the date is today - it will give yesterday
If the date is a Monday - it will give Friday and if Friday was a holiday it will give Thursday
I have another function which gives NULL if the provided date is a working date and gives the details of the date if it a holiday/weekend
select dbo.fn_working_day(@date)

But I am just not able to find a way to add a filter to just count the last 5 working days (or whatever number is given in @dataretentionPeriod variable)
I even tried this to grab the last 5 working date
declare @i int =0, 
        @date datetime, 
        @newdate datetime, 
        @daten datetime = '2024-04-04', 
        @datet datetime
while @i  <5
Begin
select @date = convert(datetime,convert(varchar, dbo.fn_previous_working_day(@daten-@i),112))
select @datet = convert(datetime,convert(varchar, dbo.fn_previous_working_day(@date),112))
select @newdate = @datet
set @i = @i+1
end
select @newdate

But it gives me 27-04-2024 instead of 2024-04-26 as there are two public holidays in that week and the counter is only jumping by 1 day not 1 working day - how can i make the counter jump by 1 working day instead of 1 day
I am expecting the date filter to only consider 5 working days instead of just 5 days

A calendar table would be well worth the effort.  Just an aside, LOOPS should be avoided at all costs.

Side note: Converting dates to/from text for comparisons or other operations is a bad practice to be avoided. If a value is a date or date/time, store it as the appropriate type and limit operations to native date/time operators and functions. The WHERE condition in your first code block would be better written as WHERE pt.ptStampDateTime < DATEADD(DAY, @DataRetentionPeriod * -1, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())). The text conversions in the original condition are not sargable, meaning indexes can't be used.

Dale K I was adding sqlDeveloper and the tag showed oracle-sqldeveloper - so i added it believing that it is for both oracle and sql developer

If you are seriously still using 2008 R2 you need to investigate an urgent upgrade path.

If you can assume (should be fine for most countries) that the longest calendar span to consider is 10days in which we could always find 5 working days (you can adjust if not):
with Seq as (
    select Offset 
    from (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) T (Offset)
), Last10Days as (
    select dateadd(day,-Offset, getdate()) as Dte
    from Seq
)
select top 5 *
from Last10Days L10D
where dbo.fn_working_day(Dte) is null 
-- I simulated with this (I don't have your function)
-- exists (select 1 as IsWeekDay where datename(weekday, L10D.Dte) not in ('Saturday', 'Sunday'))
order by Dte desc

We build a calendar of last 10days, and test all with your function, retaining  the working days, then take the most recent 5

10 days isn't always enough; the op said there are two public holidays is one week. This means that you could have two Saturdays, two Sundays and two public holidays, leaving only 4 working days, when you actually want 5.

Thanks@matbailie, we can just add ,(11),(12),(13),(15) after (10) to increase the window to 15 days. Or more
